# SQL - Sortear linhas aleatórias

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Dada a tabela como exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu quero sortear, entre as linhas com o mesmo número de ordem, uma única linha, ou seja, uma da ordem 1, uma da ordem 2 e uma da ordem 3, aleatoriamente. **Eu preciso de uma solução genérica, que se aplica a uma tabela com n ordens.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dá pra fazer com ROW_NUMBER() também...

```
SELECT ORDEM, RODADA
FROM 
(
    SELECT ORDEM, RODADA, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ORDEM ORDER BY NEWID()) AS ROWORDER
    FROM #TMP_RODADAS
) TEMP
WHERE 
    ROWORDER = 1
```

Answer (score 4):

Tente assim:

```
SELECT t.ordem,
       (SELECT TOP 1 rodada FROM tabela WHERE ordem = t.ordem ORDER BY NEWID())
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ordem FROM tabela) t
```

**[Veja no SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/79139/2/0)**

A chamada para o `NEWID()` dentro do `ORDER BY` gera um GUID para cada linha retornada. Não é exatamente aleatório, mas é genérico e simples o suficiente, já que SQL Server não tem nenhuma função específica para gerar um número aleatório.

Comment: Por que precisa desse "t" no final da query?

Comment: Esse "t" é o que chamamos de "alias". É basicamente o nome que eu dei para o sub-select de baixo `(SELECT DISTINCT...)`. Nesse caso, eu usei esse alias para diferenciar os dois sub-selects. Caso contrário, na cláusula WHERE do sub-select de cima `(WHERE ordem = t.ordem)`, o SQL não saberia à qual `ordem` eu estava me referindo. Espero que dê para entender...

Comment: Valeu @VítorMartins!!!

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução é utilizar uma `subquery` com `ROW_NUMBER` utilizando `PARTITION BY` pela coluna que deseja que seja o agrupamento e ordenando por `NEW_ID` que garantirá a randomização:

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.ordem ORDER BY NEWID()) AS sequencia,
               t.*
          FROM tabela t) x
 WHERE sequencia <= 1
```

---

Na `query` acima:

- Utilizamos o `ROW_NUMBER` para obtermos o retorno dos agrupamentos que será usado fora da `subquery`;
- Realizamos o `PARTITION BY` pela coluna que será utilizada para agrupar;
- Ordenamos pelo `NEW_ID` que garantirá que a sequencia será aleatória;
- Utilizamos a coluna resultante (no caso `sequencia`) para limitar o número de registros que queremos por agrupamento (no exemplo seria apenas 1 por grupo);

---

> [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186734(v=sql.120).aspx)
>
> Retorna o número sequencial de uma linha em uma partição de um conjunto de resultados, iniciando em 1 para a primeira linha de cada partição.

---

> [`NEWID`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newid-transact-sql)
>
> Creates a unique value of type `uniqueidentifier`.

Em tradução livre:

> Cria um valor único do tipo `uniqueidentifier`;

Answer (score 0):

aproveitando a ideia do colega Vitor para o order by newid(), porque me parece que o rand() não funcionou.

```
select distinct 
    t.ordem,
    (select top 1 
         x.rodada 
     from temp x 
     where x.ordem = t.ordem 
     order by newid()) as rodada
from temp t
```

veja no SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a95f7/2

Comment: sua solução é específica para essa situação, eu preciso de uma genérica, a tabela foi só um exemplo, expliquei melhor a pergunta agora.

Comment: alterei a resposta e coloquei no sql fiddle